# Get facebook page review and rating

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have created a facebook app and approved the app to access manage_pages.I am looking for php code to get page access from page to get the page information.

For getting reviews and rating I am using the below code

```html
require 'facebook-php-sdk-master/src/facebook.php';



$config = array();
$config['appId'] = '1489047331XXXXX';
$config['secret'] = '6ac210360aad27ab1044e4201XXXX';

$facebook = new Facebook($config);

print_r($facebook);

try {
 // 466400200079875 is Facebook id of Fan page https://www.facebook.com/pontikis.net
 $ret = $facebook->api("/page_id/ratings?field=open_graph_story", 'GET');
 print_r($ret);
} catch(Exception $e) {
 echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

I am getting the below error

(#210) This call requires a Page access token.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Comment: I'm getting `Fatal error: Class 'Facebook' not found`

Comment: you have to include facebook library file

Comment: I got Graph returned an error: (#10) To use 'Page Public Content Access' error. please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create new object like this and set access_token if not exists:

```
        $fb = new Facebook([
        'app_id' => FB_APP_ID,
        'app_secret' => FB_APP_SECRET,
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
        'default_access_token' => isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']) ?
            $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] : FB_APP_ID . '|'. FB_APP_SECRET
    ]);
```

Change FB_APP_ID and FB_APP_SECRET, only with yours. Now you have access token, after that you can make requests and get data that u need access token for it like this (for the example):

```
    $request = $fb->request('GET', '/'.$page_id.'/');
    // Send the request to Graph
    try {
        $response = $fb->getClient()->sendRequest($request);
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        // When Graph returns an error
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }

    $graphNode = $response->getGraphPage();

    var_dump($graphNode->all());
```

Where $page_id is id of some page, where you can find it with its FB page URL .